# rails 4.1 Activeadmin with paperclip, add image button pressed no response

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip, activeadmin

I want to upload images to a place in active admin dashboard by paperclip, but When i pressed "add new place picture", nothing happened. Image as below:
[image]

**model/place.rb**

```
class Place < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :place_pictures,     :dependent => :destroy, 
                                :autosave => true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :place_pictures, 
                                :allow_destroy => true
end
```

**model/place_picture.rb**

```
class PlacePicture < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :place

  attr_accessible :picture, :logo
  has_attached_file :picture, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" },
                              :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :picture, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

**admin/place.rb**
    ActiveAdmin.register Place do

```
    form :html => { :enctype => "multipart/form-data" } do |f|
      f.inputs "Place details" do
        f.input :name
        f.input :about
        f.has_many :place_pictures do |ff|
          ff.input :picture, :as => :file, :hint => ff.template.image_tag(ff.object.picture.url(:thumb))
          ff.input :logo, as: :boolean, :label => "isLogo"
        end       
      end
     f.actions
    end

   index do
      column :id
      column :name
      column :city
      column :about
      column "Images" do |place|
          if !(place.place_pictures.empty?)
            ul do
               place.place_pictures.each do |img|
                  li do
                    image_tag(img.picture.url(:thumb))
                  end
               end
             end
            end
         end
      actions
     end

    show do |ad|
      attributes_table do
        row :name
        row :city
        row :about
        row :image do
          if !(place.place_pictures.empty?)
            ul do
          place.place_pictures.each do |img|
            li do
            image_tag(img.picture.url(:thumb))
          end
         end
        end
        end
      end
     end
     #active_admin_comments
   end
 end
```

**Gemfile:**

```
gem 'rails'#version 4.1.8
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'activeadmin'
gem "paperclip", "~> 4.2"
```

It worked well before on rails 3.x and active_admin 0.6.x. Any help? thanks!

UPDATE:
Finally change active_admin.js to below, it works! don't know why! hope help anyone if has this situation.

```
 // = require jquery
 // = require jquery_ujs
 // = require active_admin/base
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the javascript that appends the fields (has_many), doesn't work. Do you have any JavaScript runtime on your system? Node.js for example.

https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs

Comment: I don't think it's JavaScript runtime issue, but i still installed Node.js, no help. Thanks your answer.